# Is it safe to minify JavaScript code that might run alongside other scripts?

Tags: javascript, conflict, minify, google-closure

For example, in aggressive mode, Google Closure will rename functions. If someone includes my closure compiled script alongside another script someone else also compiled with closure, are renaming conflicts likely to occur?

In short, I want to minify my code, but it will be used on other websites and I want to avoid conflicts with other scripts.

Comment: You've asked the wrong question with Closure, or minifiers, since you *ALWAYS* have to worry about collissions of variables defined in the global scope in JavaScript, *REGARDLESS* of whether you minify your scripts or not.  Use a functional closure wrapper to wrap your code if you want to minimize chances of collission.

Comment: Closure's Advanced Mode only makes the potential collissions worse, as it compiles many objects into new global objects for the fastest preformance.  That's why Closure's Advanced Mode is used best with all the program files at once, never piece-meal.

Comment: I see. So scripts like http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js must not be aggressively minimized, as they work on thousands of webpages around the world without collisions. I suppose a better question would have been, "Is there any way to minify a script in a way that minimizes possible collisions with other scripts [written by other people that might be included alongside my script]?" Thank you for the information and I apologize for my poor wording.

Comment: Things like `ga.js` are designed so that they expose only a few objects to the global scope and everything else wrapped up in a closure.  The file itself is aggressively optimized.  Beware -- the fact that it is minimized/not-minimized has nothing to do with collissions.  You can have a plain-script JavaScript file with tons of collissions, or you can have a heavily-optimized script with no collissions.

Comment: Collissions have nothing to do with minification or variable renaming.  You avoid collissions by avoiding creating objects in the global scope.  Anything else that is not created in the global scope does not collide with other scripts.

Comment: Just your case in point: you **CAN** collide `ga.js` if you load another script which overwrites the `_gat` and `_gaq` global variables.  Try it, and Google Analytics will no longer work.  In other words, `ga.js` works with different web pages not because it is collission free, but because it creates global variables (i.e. _gat and _gaq) with names that are very unlikely to be chosen by other scripts.

Comment: Thank you Stephen - that answers the question I was trying to ask. I understood that anything in the global scope could have collisions, but I did not understand that most everything in a script like ga.js was wrapped in a closure. If you posted that as an answer, I would upvote it. Thanks again!

Comment: thanks.  Since you mention it, I've made it into an answer!  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ALWAYS have to worry about collisions of variables defined in the global scope in JavaScript, **REGARDLESS** of whether you minify your scripts or not. Use a functional closure wrapper to wrap your code if you want to minimize chances of collision.

Closure's Advanced Mode only makes the potential collisions worse, as it compiles many objects into new global objects (which are named similarly, e.g. `a`, `b` etc.) for the fastest performance. That's why Closure's Advanced Mode is used best with **all** the program files at once, never piecemeal.

Things like `ga.js` (Google Analytics) are designed so that they expose only a few objects to the global scope and everything else wrapped up in a closure. The file itself is aggressively optimized. Beware -- the fact that it is minimized/not-minimized has nothing to do with collisions. You can have a plain-script JavaScript file with tons of collisions, or you can have a heavily-optimized script with no collisions.

Collisions have nothing to do with minification or variable renaming. You avoid collisions by avoiding creating objects in the global scope. Anything else that is not created in the global scope does not collide with other scripts.  For example, you **CAN** collide `ga.js` if you load another script which overwrites the `_gat` or `_gaq` global variables. Try it, and Google Analytics will no longer work. In other words, `ga.js` works with different web pages **not** because it is collision-free, but because it creates global variables (i.e. `_gat` and `_gaq`) with names that are very *unlikely* to be chosen by other scripts.

Answer (score -2):

You'd be better off using YUICompressor, it's a lot less aggressive and tends not to minify anything that looks to be external.

Check it out:- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Comment: So are you saying there **would** be conflicts if I used an aggressive minifyer? Because I do want to use aggressive if possible. It seems to work for Google. For example, the Analytics JS includes seem to be aggressively compiled, but yet they never seem to conflict with anything. Thank you again.

Comment: There's always a chance of conflicts with aggressive minification, see Stephen Chungs comment above.